# Visual Studio 2012 compatibility with TFS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compatibility

I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5 on my local PC and Team Foundation Server Express 2013 Version 12.0.40629.0(Tfs2013.Update5) install on server on local network.

I am following this link for configuring TFS and adding project:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1095480/Team-Foundation-Server-TFS

My user have admin rights while working on TFS Server. I have add collection through TFS Admin Console but unable to add new project. There is no option to add project in the web.
On Fig.29, a message popup stating: TF30172: You are trying to create a team project either without required permissions or with an older version of Team Explorer.

What could be the issue? Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [Client compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements#client-compatibility):

> Only the latest version of VS and Team Explorer has "full"
>   compatibility with the latest Team Foundation Server, because this
>   will be the only client that contains components that can interface
>   with new features for that release, and will also be the only client
>   from which you can perform certain administrative tasks such as
>   creating new team projects.

You have to use VS/Team Explorer 2013 and newer version to create team projects.

Comment: It says for VS2012/TFS2013: High level of support. Supports Git with Visual Studio Tools for Git extension.
Admin uninstalled TFS2013 and installed TFS2012 and it configured easily without error. Maybe it was edition conflict rather than version conflict.

Anyway, thanks for helping. :)

Comment: VS 2012 could work with TFS 2013, but creating team projects, you need  VS/Team Explorer 2013 and newer version.